# Automatic date filling and sumbitting jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have three boxes I need to fill before submitting form. It's "year", "month" and "day". I need to get a script that will fill these boxes automatically (for example 1980-1998, day by day, month by month). I know I need to use these formulas (where "month" is a string):

```
$('input[name="year"]').value = '1980';
$('select[name="month"]').value = '01';
$('input[name="day"]').value = '1';
$('button[type="submit"]').click();
```

but I'm not sure how to create a working loop for day, month and year (it will also need to submit itself at end of every loop). I also need to have a small timeout like 4 or 5 seconds between each loop.

(I forgot password to my account, I've set a random birthday date when i registered so I need to get a script that will test every date :<)

this is how the boxes look like

[image]

Comment: `$('input[name="year"]').value = '1980';` should be `$('input[name="year"]').val('1980');`

Comment: this one doesn't work when I put it into console ;>
i get this:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:25

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: please check with $('input[name="year"]') and check with output what wit will return

Comment: i get this: <input type="tel" class="valid date-input sc-gZMcBi hAYZKM" name="year" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Rok" maxlength="4" value="">

im not sure if this is all you're asking?

Comment: To answer your question we need to know how the html form works, usually if you click submit it reloads the whole site unless it's AJAX and even then it might change the form with a message or something. So you cannot simply run your code in a loop. Also most likely the server has a human verification check (like a captcha) or it blocks subsequent request after some tries...

Comment: the box does not load again. After submitting, you just get the message that the data you put is invalid. All the boxes are filled same way as before submitting.

Comment: you can try doing it yourself - https://profil.tlen.pl/odzyskaj/ first you need to type an email, try: "stacktest@o2.pl", in the second step you need to choose second square "Pytanie pomocnicze". You will get these boxes; first one is the question, answer is Eleven and then i need to fill date ("Miesiąc" means Month, then Styczen = January etc)
rok = year, dzień = day

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).